# Thymeleaf exception , trying to resolve .png as template

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

i have a simple controller that take request put data and redirect to view

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/ts")
public class MainController {

@GetMapping("/initiate/{templateName}")
public String getTemplate(Model model, @PathVariable("templateName") String templateName) throws IOException {
    model.addAllAttributes(new ObjectMapper().readValue("{ \"dy_t1\": \"This is the text 2\" , \"dy_Lorem\":\"This is the lorem text\"}", HashMap.class));
    return templateName;
}
```

}

When i am calling http://localhost:8092/ts/initiate/greeting , it is landing on greeting template just fine and showing the page with the populated data.

```
greeting.html 

<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
 <head>
<title>Getting Started: Serving Web Content</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
<a href="#"><img src="logo-mobile@2x.png" /></a>
<p th:text="'Hello, ' + ${dy_t1} + '!'" /> 
</body>
</html>
```

But when i am checkin the console it is saying :

org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "logo-mobile@2x.png", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers

Why it is trying to resolve .png files present in the src of greeting.html , if i remove this src then it dont push this error.

Comment: what does your template look like?

Comment: pasted the template above..

Comment: This is the proper way to include images in templates: `<img th:src="@{/images/test.png}"/>`

Comment: works fine for me. https://gitlab.com/supun/spring-boot-app